# Link dynamic database to new workbook in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a database of data in excel that I want to copy and paste (link) to a new sheet where I can manipulate the data to a more readable form. However, the database does not have a set number of cells and updates regularly (the reason why it needs to be linked). The database changes size on a daily basis either shrinking or expanding. Is there a way to link the database even though it need to be a dynamic range?

Comment: So the 'Database' lives in an Excel sheet? You want to create a second Excel sheet and use something like a pivot?

Comment: Yes, the database lives in an excel sheet, it is updated by a manufacturing planning system. I want to create a second excel sheet where I can sort an graph data, I won't be able to use the built in pivot function that excel has because the data is too complicated (I tried the built-in pivot first, but it couldn't give all the info I needed). So, I think I will have to sort the data with VBA code and then extract it for the graph somehow.

Comment: @RazorSky basically I just need to link the entire spreadsheet of the database with the new document (which I did actually try just to be sure but my computer couldn't handle the massive amount of information)

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation for one of my reports where I don't want to mess with the live data. All I do is create the link by going to the new sheet and typing something like `=iferror(C:\USER\Database.xlsx\sheet1!A1," ")` and fill across all the way and down all the way. The iferror checks for data and if there is no data inserts a space. That is how you can overcome the dynamic columns and with issues. The new spreadsheet will then be linked to the raw data set and you can manipulate it as needed.

Comment: For some reason, my fill handle to drag the formula won't work? Did that happen to  you?

Comment: I don't think this is going to work because the problem still exists that I have to work with the assumption that I don't know how many rows will be in the spreadsheet. So, I can't copy down the link to a certain number of rows the spreadsheet will just be too big especially since I am working already with over 1500 rows.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say you don't know how many rows you are speaking rows like 1,2,3,4,5... not A,B,C,D,E...? As long as you have the same number of columns it shouldn't matter, and rows just show up as blanks.